# Copy values from one dataframe into another by column with dates values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this df1:

```
date                   key1     key2
01/01/2020  0:00:00    1         11
01/01/2020  0:00:00    2         12
01/01/2020  0:00:00    3         13
01/01/2020  0:00:00    4         14
```

And other df2:

```
date                   key1     
01/01/2020  0:00:00    888            
01/01/2020  1:00:00    888
```

I would like to replace the values on df1 with the ones from df2, taking into account the column date. So the result should be this one:

```
date                   key1     key2
01/01/2020  0:00:00    888       11
01/01/2020  0:30:00    2         12
01/01/2020  1:00:00    888       13
01/01/2020  1:30:00    4         14
```

Comment: Where does `01/01/2020  0:30:00`  or `01/01/2020  1:30:00` come from? Which conditions do you want to satisfy in order to obtain the desired output?

Comment: The original dataset is df1, so I have to keep it with the full information. However, I realize that some values wrong, so I have the correct one in df2, I just need copy them into df1, so the result will be like the last dataframe